# How can distribute 100 one number at a time

Tags: javascript, ractivejs

I have to following array:

```
var collections=[
    {value:20, next:"", prev: "", lastUpdated: false, isLoaked: false, pointer: false},
  {value:20, next:"", prev: "", lastUpdated: false, isLoaked: false, pointer: false},
  {value:20, next:"", prev: "", lastUpdated: false, isLoaked: false, pointer: false},
  {value:20, next:"", prev: "", lastUpdated: false, isLoaked: false, pointer: false},
  {value:20, next:"", prev: "", lastUpdated: false, isLoaked: false, pointer: false}
];
```

Useing the following iteration, I can calculate the `next` and `prev`:

```
for(i = 0; i < collections.length; i++) {
    collections[i].next = (i+1) % collections.length;
  collections[i].prev = i > 0 ? i-1 : collections.length-1;
}
```

Following is the result:

```
var collections=[
    {value:20, next:"1", prev: "3", lastUpdated: false, isLoaked: false, pointer: false},
  {value:20, next:"2", prev: "0", lastUpdated: false, isLoaked: false, pointer: false},
  {value:20, next:"3", prev: "1", lastUpdated: false, isLoaked: false, pointer: false},
  {value:20, next:"4", prev: "2", lastUpdated: false, isLoaked: false, pointer: false},
  {value:20, next:"0", prev: "3", lastUpdated: false, isLoaked: false, pointer: false}
];
```

Based on the new collections, I need to calculate each value if the pointer is `increased` or `decreased`

Example: The value for 3rd item has been increased to 25

```
var collections=[
    {value:20, next:"1", prev: "3", lastUpdated: false, isLoaked: false, pointer: false},
  {value:20, next:"2", prev: "0", lastUpdated: false, isLoaked: false, pointer: false},
  {value:25, next:"3", prev: "1", lastUpdated: false, isLoaked: false, pointer: true},
  {value:20, next:"4", prev: "2", lastUpdated: false, isLoaked: false, pointer: false},
  {value:20, next:"0", prev: "3", lastUpdated: false, isLoaked: false, pointer: false}
];
```

Expected Result:

```
0: {value: 19, next: 1, prev: 4, lastUpdated: true, isLoaked: false, pointer: false}
1: {value: 19, next: 2, prev: 0, lastUpdated: true, isLoaked: false, pointer: false}
2: {value: 25, next: 3, prev: 1, lastUpdated: true, isLoaked: false, pointer: true}
3: {value: 18, next: 4, prev: 2, lastUpdated: true, isLoaked: false, pointer: false}
4: {value: 19, next: 0, prev: 3, lastUpdated: true, isLoaked: false, pointer: false}
```

Example 2: if the value is decreased to 2 for the same pointer.

```
var collections=[
    {value:19, next:"1", prev: "3", lastUpdated: false, isLoaked: false, pointer: false},
  {value:19, next:"2", prev: "0", lastUpdated: false, isLoaked: false, pointer: false},
  {value:23, next:"3", prev: "1", lastUpdated: false, isLoaked: false, pointer: true},
  {value:18, next:"4", prev: "2", lastUpdated: false, isLoaked: false, pointer: false},
  {value:19, next:"0", prev: "3", lastUpdated: false, isLoaked: false, pointer: false}
];
```

Following result is expected which with follow the `prev`:

```
0: {value: 20, next: 1, prev: 4, lastUpdated: true, isLoaked: false, pointer: false}
1: {value: 20, next: 2, prev: 0, lastUpdated: true, isLoaked: false, pointer: false}
2: {value: 23, next: 3, prev: 1, lastUpdated: false, isLoaked: false, pointer: true}
3: {value: 18, next: 4, prev: 2, lastUpdated: false, isLoaked: false, pointer: false}
4: {value: 19, next: 0, prev: 3, lastUpdated: false, isLoaked: false, pointer: false}
```

So far I have the following code:

```
var collections=[
    {value:20, next:"", prev: "", lastUpdated: false, isLoaked: false, pointer: false},
  {value:20, next:"", prev: "", lastUpdated: false, isLoaked: false, pointer: false},
  {value:20, next:"", prev: "", lastUpdated: false, isLoaked: false, pointer: false},
  {value:20, next:"", prev: "", lastUpdated: false, isLoaked: false, pointer: false},
  {value:20, next:"", prev: "", lastUpdated: false, isLoaked: false, pointer: false}
];
var maxValue = 100;
var totalValue = 0;
var toBeDistributedNext = 0;
var toBeDistributedPrev = 0;

for(i = 0; i < collections.length; i++) {
    collections[i].next = (i+1) % collections.length;
  collections[i].prev = i > 0 ? i-1 : collections.length-1;
}

collections[2].value = 25;
collections[2].pointer = true;

collections.forEach(function (collection) {
  totalValue += parseInt(collection.value);
});

if (totalValue > maxValue) {
    toBeDistributedNext = totalValue - maxValue;
} else {
    toBeDistributedPrev = maxValue - totalValue;
}
var currentPointer = collections.find(item => item.pointer === true);
for (let i = 0; i < toBeDistributedNext; i++) {
  var nextIndex = currentPointer.next;
  if (!collections[i%collections.length].pointer) {
    collections[i%collections.length].value--;
    collections[i%collections.length].lastUpdated = true;
    console.log(collections[i%collections.length])
    //currentPointer = collections[i%collections.length].next;
  }
}
```

The above code gives the following result: which is WRONG

```
0: {value: 19, next: 1, prev: 4, lastUpdated: true, isLoaked: false, …}
1: {value: 19, next: 2, prev: 0, lastUpdated: true, isLoaked: false, …}
2: {value: 25, next: 3, prev: 1, lastUpdated: false, isLoaked: false, …}
3: {value: 19, next: 4, prev: 2, lastUpdated: true, isLoaked: false, …}
4: {value: 19, next: 0, prev: 3, lastUpdated: true, isLoaked: false, …}
```

The last is not calculating, any one please help. **The total has to be 100**.

I have the JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tanvir_alam_shawn/zm21pLen/144/

Comment: Why do you need this variables: `lastUpdated: false, isLoaked: false, pointer: false`?

Comment: I was trying many different ways to do it, but I was failing. the main one is `value: 19, next: 1, prev: 4, isLoaked: false`. `isLocked` for locking it so it does not change. So, if 100 is total distribution: and you lock 20, you have 80 to distribute to rest.

Comment: Please describe more precise why do you need this variables: `next, prev, lastUpdated, isLoaked, pointer`

Comment: Should we read `isLoaked` as `isLocked` or it has some special meaning?

Comment: @Anton it really doesn't not matter, the naming will change anyway. The main reason I stated `prev` and `next`, is because I wanted to `distributed` one by one using `next` index and `steal` one by one using `prev` index. As you can see the number is `distributed | stolen` one by one. Hope I made it clear. if you can show me how to do all those without these attributes. am willing to accept it. The main issue is `distribute | steal` and total amount is always 100, and if one is locked with 20, we have 80 to be `distributed | stolen`. hope I was clear. u can look at the Jsfiddle

Comment: @Anton sorry for spelling mistake but its `isLocked`

Comment: Can it happen that not 1, but 2 values will change? For example `collections = [25, 20, 25, 20, 20]` (so I add 5 to first and third element).

Comment: @Anton No, you have distribute one by one, 5 will be distributed, Hence if the pointer in the first one then depending on `prev` or `next` 4 of them, Please have a look at this fiddle: I did it but its doest not work 100 % of the time: https://jsfiddle.net/tanvir_alam_shawn/sncxLz8d/